# How to clone branches in a fork (GuiHub)

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository a while ago, but since then, the main repository has had a couple of branches added, but those branches don't appear on the fork... how do I copy the branches over?

If I can't do that, what happens to the commit history in the main repository if the fork is deleted? I don't want to loose my commit history/pull requests (that have been merged) to the main repository.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do it from GitHub, but from the command line, you would add the original repo as a remote and then fetch, something like (inside the forked git repo)

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/branchname
```

You could then `push` those branches back up to the fork on GitHub:

```
git push origin branchname
```